# How to serarch from JSON data with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new in MongoDB. I am using MongoDB 3.6.3. I have one fields in the document with huge josn data and I don't know all key names present inside JSON data.
Now I want to search documents by the value which will present in any key inside JSON data.
I have tried using this.

```
db.getCollection('booking').find({'result.important_information': /.*small dogs*/})
```

But this required key for search But I dont have key name I have to search using the only value.

Comment: try this
 db.getCollection('booking').find({'result.important_information': { $regex: /small dogs/ } })

Comment: this is working fine with key but I want without giving key.My value is a large JSON data whose 1 key is important_information So I want like this way  db.getCollection('booking').find({'result': { $regex: /small dogs/ } })

Comment: can you post your sample JSON